# HorizontalListView returns wrong position in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using HorizontalListView tutorial from:
http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/06/horizontal-listview-tutorial.html

My problem is, when try to scroll right to left in HorizontalListView, position of clicked item comes correct but when I try to scroll from left to right and click on any item then position resets back to 0, 1, 2 etc. and my HorizontalListView.getCount() returns 0.